# Как выбрать правильную форму: колышет или колыхает, брызжет или брызгает?

Tags: грамматика

Существует целый ряд глаголов с разными вариантами спряжении:  ***колышет – колыхает,  брызжет – брызгает, каплет – капает, движет – двигает, мечет – метает,***  Иногда формы различаются **по стилю** (в разговорной форме обычно сохраняется глагольный суффикс), но могут ли они различаться **по смыслу** и в чем это различие?

Существует  ли для всех глаголов **общий различающий семантический фактор**? Как  вариантные формы спряжения объясняет **историческая грамматика**?

Comment: Вопрос внутренне противоречив. Если слова различаются по смыслу, то это **разные** слова, которые уже нельзя объединить в подобную пару, нет? Но вообще-то "мечет" и "метает", равно как и "движет" и "двигает", для меня различаются по смыслу

Answer (score 1):

Кто-то поднял вопрос в топ (может, бот). И уже убрал из топа.

Параллельные формы избыточных глаголов могут различаться стилистически и по смыслу и иметь разные сферы употребления.

Капает - падает каплями, каплет - протекает, пропускает по каплям влагу.
Таким образом, правильно: вода капает с крыш, но: крыша каплет.

Движет - по отношению к абстрактному понятию. Например: движет процессом, движет поведением, движет тенденцией. То есть как синоним слова `управляет`. Двигает - по отношению к физическим предметам.

Ветер колышет ветки деревьев. Но: мать колыхает младенца.

Водопад брызжет. Но: брызгать воду на растения.

Метает кинжалы. Но: мечет по комнате или рыба мечет икру.

То есть в принципе в таких парах значение иногда совпадает, но сфера употребления отличается. Если не придерживаться этого, то будет звучать очень неестественно и резать слух.

Answer (score 0):

Разница в рождении действия. Для одних глаголов (для "наглядности" примера - указанных Вами), действие является внешним проявлением, для других - внутренним. Разумеется, указанное действие не основывается на физических законах, но показывает отношение говорящего к предмету обсуждения.

Пример: "теща мечется, от злости забыла где дверь" и "теща метается в поисках тапочек любимому зятю".